# Does GLS require an assumed distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, assumptions, generalized-least-squares

I am wondering if it makes sense to talk about Generalized Least Squares (GLS)  without assuming a distribution on the residuals, or if it comes with implicit assumptions of normality on the residuals $\epsilon$.

Explicitly I am assuming a linear model: $Y = X \beta  + \epsilon$. The $Y_i$ are not assumed independent.

$$E(\epsilon) = 0$$ 
$$V(\epsilon) = \Sigma $$

In some notes I have, I see the derivation of $\hat{\beta}$ assuming a multivariate normal distribution (and naively assuming $\Sigma$ is known) imposed on $\epsilon$.

This leads to $\hat{\beta}_{GLS} = (X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X'\Sigma^{-1}Y$.

Is there a way to argue this without employing a maximum likelihood argument?

Comment: Normality is required only for $\hat\beta$ to be normal in small samples. Asymptotically, this is not necessary. This is in line with the linear regression model where normality is not needed except for the small sample distritbution of $\hat\beta$.